# paypal rest api credential via oauth

Tags: php, oauth, paypal, openid

I'm using paypal's rest API

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/

Whenever I use API to fetch orders etc I need a id and secret key to request access token. Then I can fetch them.

I'm thinking is there anyway to get the id and secret key via OAuth? Just like [storenvy.com](http://storenvy.com) does. They connect with paypal login. Then fetches the orders / transactions.

Any idea?

Comment: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/ug_sandbox

Comment: I'm tired of reading API docs. Can you tell me is it possible or not?

Comment: i think APP ID and Secret key has been provided when registered. or maybe i am not clear by your question :(

Comment: I've app id and secret. I'm getting user profile info. Now I wanna get user's API credential so that I can use it to pull transactions.

Comment: who is user? who have shop or who will be shopping?
i think you will have a format and your client/shop owners can submit their API credentials. then customer/who shop can login on PAYPAL with your app via shop owners API credentials. Is it like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry didn't notice this question until now - this is currently not possible. What we intend to support in the near future is a way to obtain an Oauth access token from a merchant so you can make API calls on-behalf of them. No need to share API credentials. This is not yet available but will be available hopefully soon.

Comment: so you are saying i can't connect my paypal app to a merchant account via oauth and make transactions on their behalf yet?! when will this be available?

Comment: Sorry don't have the specific dates yet but should be available in Q3/Q4 timeframe (definitely this year).

Comment: @Praveen It seems this is still not possible in 2017! Is that right?

Comment: @praveen Has the near future arrived?

Comment: I no longer work at PayPal - but you guys might want to check https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/reference/api-requests/#authorization - seems like it's been added.