# Make PayPal REST API request on behalf of merchant via OAuth

Tags: rest, paypal, oauth

I want to add PayPal REST API capabilities to our shop software. Unfortunately it seems there is no way to automate to process of connecting the merchants account to our system. It looks like if you use the REST API you need to ask for client ID and secret. Then you trade that information for an OAuth token. However this is not the normal OAuth flow, which has a step that asks for users permission and does not require credentials to begin with.

These two topics basically cover the same issue, but are rather stale:

[paypal rest api credential via oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852629/paypal-rest-api-credential-via-oauth)

[Is it possible to use `Log In with PayPal` to make REST api requests on behalf of the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19018608/is-it-possible-to-use-log-in-with-paypal-to-make-rest-api-requests-on-behalf-o)

Does anybody know if this is possible in the meantime? I find it rather strange to design a RESTful API with OAuth capabilities and then not using it by allowing people to automatically ask for access rights on behalf of the merchant? This makes is somewhat useless for all shop software doesn't it? Well at least inconvenient.

Or is there maybe a way one could use the old API to obtain an access token that can also be used with the REST API?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the [Permissions API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/permissions-service/gs_PermissionsService/)?

Comment: But this is using the classic API, right? I'm looking to try to do this as well, but from the other posts linked here (and utterly failing at everything I've tried today) it seems like PayPal doesn't yet support this. It's very confusing, though, because the REST docs seem to imply that it does.

Comment: Yeah, just seems like something that isn't quite available in the REST API yet.  They'll get there, but who knows when.  I've been sticking to the Classic API's because everything I really want to do seems to not be there yet in REST.

Comment: But yes, in theory, it looks like you should be able to use Login with PayPal, obtain an auth token for the user, and then use that token in REST calls accordingly.  Have you tried that specifically?

Comment: As I understand it, the Login with Paypal functionality is to allow users to log into your site using Paypal credentials, like OpenID or Facebook login, so in my understanding it's a completely different concept. The wording of the methods is extremely confusing, I thought Paypal login was the way to go in the beginning, too.